# How do I get ordered list according to culture?

Tags: c#, lambda, cultureinfo

It may be dublicated question but there is something wrong in my project. Books' names are including multibyte strings like `Ç`, `Ğ`, `İ`, `Ş`, `Ö`, `Ü`. If I use them without culturing like this:

```
private readonly LinqtoSQLiteDataContext _connection = new LinqtoSQLiteDataContext();
var books = _connection.books.OrderBy(f => f.name);
GridControlBooks.DataSource = books;
```

The output looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But, `İnternet Ortamında Kişilik Haklarının İhlâli...` must be located after `Günümüz Türkçe'siyle Mecelle`. I tried this:

```
private readonly LinqtoSQLiteDataContext _connection = new LinqtoSQLiteDataContext();
var culture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
var books = _connection.books.OrderBy(f => f.name, StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
GridControlBooks.DataSource = books;
```

But it returns error like this:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Devart.Data.Linq.dll
Additional information: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'OrderBy'.`

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is at database level, because that is the database which sorts results in this case.

Comment: how about add `ToList()` before `OrderBy`?

Comment: try this  _connection.books.ToList().OrderBy(f => f.name, StringComparer.Create(culture, false))

Comment: @Lei Yang - Thank you very much. This is the soluton of the problem.